# Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN

Tags: oracle

I have a problem with my oracle database, I've searched/tried loads to fix the below error but I'm unable to change the status of PLSExtProc to READY :

```
lsnrctl start
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
```

Here are some information that can help :

- The oracle database starts fine
- I am using linux
- Oracle is new to me

  lsnrctl status

  ```
  Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
  STATUS of the LISTENER
  ------------------------
  Alias                     LISTENER_NAME
  Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
  Start Date                18-JUN-2016 14:36:33
  Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 11 min. 50 sec
  Trace Level               off
  Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
  SNMP                      OFF
  Listener Parameter File   /oracle/10g/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
  Listener Log File         /oracle/10g/db_1/network/log/log_file_name.log
  Listening Endpoints Summary...
    (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host2.com)(PORT=1521)))
    (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC0)))
  Services Summary...
  Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
    Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
    Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
    Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Service "orcl_XPT" has 1 instance(s).
    Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  The command completed successfully
  ```

Some variables :

```
$ORACLE_SID=orcl
$ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/10g/db_1/
```

Local_listener

```
SQL> show parameter local_listener;

NAME                     TYPE    VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
local_listener               string  ORCL
```

cat listener.ora

```
LISTENER_NAME =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host2.com)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC0))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER_NAME =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /oracle/10g/db_1/)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )
```

cat tnsnames.ora

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host1.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

    EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SID = PLSExtProc)
          (PRESENTATION = RO)
        )
      )
```

cat /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1        host1 host2 host1.com host2.com
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 2):

That is perfectly normal and expected.  Every entry in the SID_LIST section of listener.ora will show as status UNKNOWN.  That simply means the listener is taking your word for it because you listed it. Contrast that to those that show a status of READY.  These come from the database instance itself registering itself with the listener. Think of the listener as the desk clerk at a hotel. The SID_LIST section of listener.ora is the night manager handing the clerk a list of hotel guests.  The clerk has no way of knowing the accuracy of the list and so status is UNKNOWN. But if a guest walks up and says "my name is Bob. If anyone calls for me I'll be in room 201", that is the database registering with the listener.